# Historical statistics

Tags: discussion

Do you know if historical statistics from [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51674/open-data) are available? For instance, how many users we had yesterday and how many the previous day?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes... sort of.

Now that [beta sites are part of the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188465/beta-sites-should-be-in-the-data-explorer), it's possible to extract nearly all the Area 51 statistics for nearly time period you care to look at.  Here's questions/day for Open Data:

[image: Questions per day on Open Data]

You'll have to construct your own queries for the other numbers.  Remember that since the data dumps are weekly, the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) results will be missing up to 7 days of data.

The data that *isn't* readily available is traffic.  For those interested, [Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/opendata.stackexchange.com) *does* publish visitor data, but I believe it's measured differently than the numbers used for Area 51.